# Smartscreen blocking even downloads signed with EV certificate

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, certificate, code-signing, microsoft-smartscreen

In order to avoid SmartScreen blocking downloads and install files from my application, i bought an EV Code Signing Certificate ,which is expensive.

Now when i sign my installation file, Smartscreen really doesn't bother the user anymore and will let the app be installed.

BUT still, when the user try to download the install file in ZIP format from our website using Edge, Smartscreen still shows that infamous message :

```
"xxxx.zip isn't commonly downloaded. Make sure you trust xxxx.zip before you open it".
```

Then the user needs to click on [...] menu, then click on 'Keep', then another windows is show , then the user needs to click on Show more, then click again on 'Keep anyway'.

That's A LOT of friction to install a simple application on the machine.

I bought the EV code sign certificate just to avoid that, but anything changed in the download process.

The ZIP file isn't signed because you can't sign ZIP files, but the install.exe file inside of the ZIP is.

What should i do ? Download the EXE file direct, instead of the ZIP ?

Comment: Your .zip file isn’t digitally signed, the executable inside the archive, is signed.  You can sign the .zip, easier solution, digitally sign a Windows installer executable instead.  Users downloading the file is one way to increase the reputation of the file. Submitting the file to Microsoft is also another way

Comment: [OP, BTW, as a Borland user, going back to Delphi 2, I agree with your signature!]

Comment: Why exactly are you providing the installer zipped, rather than directly?

Comment: @gronostaj TBH, i always thought an EXE download would be a bad idea and somehow would be blocked by any broswer

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I love Delphi since version 3. People keep saying it's dead since early 2000s but i keep living and paying my bills coding on Delphi :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to avoid SmartScreen blocking downloads and install files from my application, i bought an EV Code Signing Certificate ,which is expensive.

> Now when i sign my installation file, Smartscreen really doesn't bother the user anymore and will let the app be installed.

> BUT still, when the user try to download the install file in ZIP format from our website using Edge, Smartscreen still shows that infamous message

If you have signed an executable that installs your application, why are you putting that executable (which is already compressed), inside of an archive? SmartScreen uses a variety of factors to determine if enough information about the file is known. Sending the sample into Microsoft, having more users download and trust the file, and even digitally signing the file that is being downloaded are ways to increase its reputation with SmartScreen.

Your archive file isn’t digitally signed. Based on the message it hasn’t been submitted to Microsoft nor have enough downloads happened, which means, SmartScreen will warn the user.

> The ZIP file isn't signed because you can't sign ZIP files, but the install.exe file inside of the ZIP is.

You can indeed sign ZIP files, I just don’t believe, using a OpenGPG certificate would make a difference to SmartScreen

> What should i do ? Download the EXE file direct, instead of the ZIP ?

Yes; You should also send the compressed executable into Microsoft, so SmartScreen other considerations can be addressed as every version of that executable, will initially not have be downloaded enough times.

Answer (score 3):

You can try making a self-extracting Zip archive (executable, *.exe*) [with 7-Zip](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables)  or other tool and then using the [MS SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool), digitally sign the file, verifying the signature.

A self-extracting archive can also be opened by 7-Zip or other archive tool *as if it were an ordinary compressed archive*, so if the certifying process works here, you might not bother to keep a separate, non-executable, Zip -- just let users know they can open the executable, examine the contents and manually extract it.